# Do certain SSL certificates / certificate authorities load faster than others?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

I've been trying to optimize my site's speed and noticed that many websites have low "Initial connection" and "SSL" times while mine are generally double of most sites that I've tested (over 110ms and 60ms, respectively). I optimized the delivery of the certificate as much as I could and it still takes the same amount of time.

So, my question is: could changing my CA make the certificate load faster?

I tried to research this but the only Google results I could find pertain to how fast the certificate authority issues the certificate, not how the certificate in question actually affects performance.

Comment: Certificates and CAs have essentially zero impact on load times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check not only the time needed for TLS but also time needed for initial connection. If the initial connection is already slower than for the other sites then the TLS handshake will be slower too - simply because the site is worse reachable from you in terms of round-trip latency.

If only TLS is slower than it is more likely that it might be caused by a bad key exchange method - which is independent of the certificate but dependent on the server configuration. RSA is the fastest key exchange but bad in terms of security. ECDHE is fast enough and recommend. But with a bad server configuration it might use DHE which is terribly slow. Also the speed of the key exchange depends on the performance of the CPU and the amount of resources available for computation: if the system is on its limits the key exchange can be significantly slower.

A major speed improvement in the TLS handshake comes also from session reuse, at least up to TLS 1.2. Thus the difference might also be caused by other sites doing session reuse and yours not.

There might be problems with TCP flow control if the certificate and chain is too large, i.e. if RSA 4096 is used (RSA 2048 is sufficient), many SAN are configured in the certificate, many intermediate certificates are sent and maybe needlessly the root CA certificate too. Optimal would be to use ECDSA certificates instead since they are smaller, but they might not be supported by all clients.

In case the client does a certificate revocation check using OCSP this might additionally slow down the handshake. Unless OCSP stapling is used by your server and supported by the client, the client needs to contact the OCSP responder of the CA to check if the certificate was revoked, which costs additional time.

---

EDIT after the target website is known:

A detailed timing shows that the TCP connection to the target website and the TLS handshake take about the same time. This is expected since the site is using TLS 1.3, i.e. TLS itself is already pretty optimized (apart from the useless inclusion of the root CA, i.e. "Contains anchor" in the report from SSLLabs).

Compared to servers like google.com the site is much slower though. This is because Google has data centers world wide and their location and routing is optimized to have a fast connection to the customer with small latency. A simple ping already shows the difference in round-trip time, which for the site in question are several factors larger than for google.com.

In other words: this is not a TLS or CA problem, but the target site simply has a worse network connection than the other sites the OP is comparing too.

Comment: @user1413341: Key exchange is part of the cipher (at least up to TLS 1.2). The cipher is usually shown somewhere in the security information about the current page, were also the certificate details are shown.  The exact details depend on the browser.

Comment: @user1413341: See my edited post. In summary: not a TLS problem but simply a slower network connection in general.  The TLS itself is pretty optimized already. You get what  you pay for in terms of performance.

Comment: I see. Network connection for my Server or the CA?

Comment: @user1413341: to your server.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case here. Without SSL, TTFB on my server is about 70ms.

Comment: @user1413341: TLS handshake with TLS 1.3 (which you use) takes one RTT (i.e. the round-trip you see in ping). The TCP handshake takes another RTT. You are limited by the RTT of your network connection and not by the something related to the certificates or TLS setup. You cannot get faster than 2 RTT for HTTPS, i.e. double the time for plain HTTP.

Comment: @user1413341 important clarification: you CA is not in the least bit involved in any network communication when people connect to your site. Switching to a new CA will not help

Comment: Could setting up OCSP Must Staple improve performance?

Comment: @user1413341: OCSP stapling is useful in general but it will not help at all if the browser does not check for revocation by OCSP in the first place - and many browsers don't. Like I said and like the SSLLabs report says you needlessly send the root CA and fixing this could lower the number of bytes send by the server. None of this will though make the 1-RTT requirement for the TLS handshake alone vanish. But the RTT is your main performance problem and this can only be fixed by having a better connectivity between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates themselves aren't very different. What may affect the performance:

- Hardware
- CA chain length, chain certificate availability, revocation checking (OCSP, CRLs)
- CA key type and size. In some cases, ECDSA signature validation may be slower than RSA (assuming PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is used), but not that dramatically

have you profiled your TLS handshake?

Comment: Hello. By profiling the TLS handshake, do you mean run it through a site like ssllabs? I've done that already and got an A+ rating. Is there something specific that I should be looking for?